# Cakephp, how to see Sqlite rowid

Tags: sqlite, rest, cakephp, primary-key, rowid

friends! I'm working with SQLite for the first time on Cakephp and I perceive that the "rowid" field (https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) is not being retrieved whem I use "Entity->load()", although it is possible to call the "Entity->findByRowid()" dynamic method.

I thought it was related to a Json view I'm using and, so, I tried to add a virtual property to the Entity adding "protected $_virtual = ['rowid']" to its class definition, but the rowid remains mull (even when I use a "regular" template.
Thus, I would like to know how to retrieve the "rowid" from a table in Cakephp.
Thanks in advances!